# Making wordpress menu remain highlighted (class="current-page-item" in the menu) for a category listing (not a page)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a site that I have completely customized the theme.

Unfortunately the theme and the way it's set up doesn't like you to view the actual page permalink for both the blog and the portfolio to view its content.

Regular pages work fine:

site.com/about
site.com/contact

However, if you go to /portfolio or /blog the pages show up blank

As a result, I had to use appearance>menu to make a custom menu that links to:

/category/portfolio/#all
/category/blog

This makes the content now show up, the only problem is when they click on the portfolio or the blog, wordpress thinks that it's not actually viewing that page, so the tab in the main menu doesnt remain highlighted (to show you what page youre currently on)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

http://eastcoastefx.com/ggqq

Thank you :)

Comment: Hey @Travis - Since your WordPress question isn't getting any love here on SO maybe you can post it at SO's sister site WordPress Answers? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. I or one of my cohorts would love to help you over there...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before. It's not pretty, but it works if both items are WordPress pages.

```
// hack the queried_object_id for wp_list_pages
global $wp_query;
$queried_object_id = $wp_query->queried_object_id;
if ($season_page) {
    // ensure season pages have Season highlighed in nav
    $wp_query->queried_object_id = 22;
}

wp_list_pages($args);

// set queried_object_id back to the original
$queried_object_id = $queried_object_id;
```

I'd be interested to know if you found anything better on the WordPress forum per **Mike Schinkel's** comment as the above is clearly a *hack*.